# "I can't place her": How do Russian speakers express this idea colloquially?

Tags: выражения

In conversation, I wanted to express the idea of "*I can't place her*" in Russian -- informally/colloquially used when you think you recognise someone from somewhere and yet, frustratingly enough, can't put your finger on from where exactly. E.g.:

> I **can't place** her, but I still feel that her face is vaguely familiar. It'll come back sometime, though it may be just that she resembles someone I know.
>
> I **can't place** her exactly, but I know she is an instructor of sorts or a teacher, can't be sure which she is, though.

In French and German, there are colloquial phrasings that perfectly match in register -- "*J'arrive pas à la remettre*", "*Ich weiß bloß gerade nicht, wo ich sie hintun soll*" -- but  its Russian equivalent eludes me.

Comment: place verb (RECOGNIZE) ​ [ T ] to recognize someone or remember where you have seen someone and how you know them: She looks familiar but I can't place her - did she use to work here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Не помню, где я ее видел" / "Не помню, откуда я ее знаю."

Answer (score 2):

"Не помню, откуда её знаю" or "не могу припомнить, откуда её знаю" - this is the most frequent thing one can hear in this kind of situations.

This can also be used for directly addressing somebody, like in "Что-то не могу тебя припомнить".

Answer (score 0):

We don't have one expression. You can say.

> Я не узнаю ее, я не знаю кто она, не могу вспомнить, кто она, я не признАю, кто она, не припомню ее, не могу точно сказать, кто она... and perhaps more.

Comment: I don't agree on "узнаю" part - "я не узнаю" is about not recognizing someone completely. I do think, howere that "примомню" might be used in this context.

Comment: place verb (RECOGNIZE)

​
[ T ] to recognize someone or remember where you have seen someone and how you know them:
She looks familiar but I can't place her - did she use to work here?

Answer (score 0):

There is a colloquiall verb for this: "упомнить", "припромнить". "Her" pronoun is ommited

There is a liitle difference in usage (I do not know english terms):

```
Сложносочинённое предложение:
- "Не могу припомнить, но её лицо смутно знакомо"
- "Не припоминаю, но её лицо смутно знакомо"

Сложноподчинённое предложение:
- "Не могу припомнить, где я её видел"
- "Не могу упомнить, где я её видел"
```